# Cols in navbar display not in full width container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to add a sticky header to my page and bootstrap provides a class for it, also I added a container to center the content and make it as wide as the content below.

But when I add a row and 12 columns not the full width of the container is taken, see below for the code.

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light sticky-header">
      <div class="container sticky-header-container">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3">test3
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">test2
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">test3
              </div>                    
          </div>
      </div>
</nav>
```

[image]

Comment: Seems to work okay for me: https://www.bootply.com/egQI9XqvuP
Make sure to use Bootstrap 3, your code doesn't work with Bootstrap 4.

Comment: The navbar has to fully spread, the container for 1240 px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a class to your row like so:

EDIT: As ZimSystem pointed out, there is a w-100 class in bootstrap, so just do:

```
<div class="row w-100">
   Your Elements
</div>
```

This should get you 100% of the containers width.

Working sample: https://www.bootply.com/J5gKTedgPr

Comment: Yep, that did the trick for desktop. But on mobile i seems that there is a right padding or margin. When i set padding or margin on 0 nothing changes (see added screenshot)

Comment: Add col classes for all sizes to your div like this: 
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">Test</div>
This should fix it on mobile as well.

Comment: https://www.bootply.com/YJLc0HXvzx Check this, i don't use sticky-header-container since it's fixed anyway. The 'container-fluid' makes it 100% wide, you can remove this if this is not what you want. But like this, for me it works on desktop and mobile.

Comment: There's no reason for `width-100` class. Bootstrap includes a `w-100` class for this.

Comment: zimsystem, when i dont add it the container is nog fully width inside the navbar

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Yep! Works (also). But stil the padding on the right (black in the picture)

Comment: Add a .no-padding{padding-left:0;padding-right:0;} to any element that should not have padding.

Comment: But in general, ZimSystem is right, the Navbar is not meant to be used like this. Creating the Navbar not the "bootstrap" way will get you in trouble sooner or later, so maybe try designing around the Navbar.

Comment: Okay, than i need to reed more :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The Bootstrap 4 Navbar isn't designed to contain the grid rows and cols. It's designed to [contain the support content](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#supported-content).

When you use a [container inside a navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#containers) it makes the container `display:flex` which is making the row you have in the container align to the start (left-side) of the container which won't fill the width.

As a workaround/hack you could revert the container to `display:block` using `d-block`, and then remove the default left/right padding from the navbar using `px-0`:

https://www.codeply.com/go/T81SqA32rJ

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top sticky-header px-0">
      <div class="container-fluid d-block sticky-header-container">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3">test3
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">test2
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">test3
              </div>                    
          </div>
      </div>
</nav>
```